# My Regex.Replace doesn't work

Tags: c#, html, regex, string

hey I am currently trying to replace html in a string. I.e `<strong>text</strong>` needs to be `<b>text</b>` 
etc. (I realize the `b` tag is considered outdated)

I am aware that I shouldn't use regex to fix this, but this is currently my only option

my code:

```
//replace strong
text = Regex.Replace(text, "<strong>.*?</strong>", "<b>$1</b>");

//replace em
text = Regex.Replace(text, "<em>.*?</em>", "<i>$1</i>");
```

the issue here is that the regex replaces the tags *and* sets the text to `$1`. how to avoid this?
(I'm in C# btw.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$1` will use the value of the first *capture* in the match. But you have not specified any capturing groups in the match, so there is nothing for `$1` to subtitute.

Use `(…)` to capture in a regex expression:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "<strong>(.*?)</strong>", "<b>$1</b>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following answer is just a workaround; it is better to write a proper regex.

```
var text = "<strong>asfdweqwe121</strong><em>test</em>";

text = text.Replace("<strong>", "<b>");
text = text.Replace("</strong>", "</b>");
text = text.Replace("<em>", "<i>");
text = text.Replace("</em>", "</i>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using:

```cs
text = Regex.Replace(text, "<strong>(.*?)</strong>", "<b>$1</b>", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Note that `RegexOptions.Singleline` is necessary to allow `.` to match line feed (LF, `\x0A`) characters, that the `.` pattern cannot match by default.